# How to define alias variable in yii?

Tags: yii, yii-components

How to define alias variable in yii?
In my yii app their are 3 types of role,

1. super-admin
2. admin,
3. user,

super admin can do admin functionalists and some more things, so
how can i define a alias role **super-admin==admin** but  not **vise-versa**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Auth Hierarchy](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.auth#defining-authorization-hierarchy) from the guide, you can define that *admin* is a child of *super-admin*, also *user* could be a child of *admin*.

You may use an extension, such as [yii-rights](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/rights/) to handle this.